# How to calculate a matrix with non-linear matrix operator?

Tags: matrices, nonlinear-system

Multivariate state estimation technique is described as follows:

$$X_e = D \cdot (D^T \otimes D)^{-1} \cdot (D^T \otimes X_o)$$

where $D$ is $n \times m$ process memory matrix, each column represents a monitoring state of the $n$ variables at a certain moment, and each row represents the monitoring states of a certain variable at $m$ moments

$D_{n \times m} = [X_{(t_1)}, X_{(t_2)}, ...X_{(t_m)}] =  {\begin{bmatrix}x_1{(t_1)} & x_1{(t_2)} & ... & x1_{(t_m)}\\x_2{(t_1)} & x_2{(t_2)} &... & x_2{(t_m)}\\\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\x_n{(t_1)} & x_n{(t_2)} & ... & x_n{(t_m)}\end{bmatrix}}_{n \times m}$

supposed I have a $D$ matrix from this data:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Time& sensor1 & sensor2 & sensor3 & sensor4 \\ \hline
07:00 & 0.23 & 0.25 & 0.22 & 0.22 \\ \hline
07:10 & 0.21 & 0.23 & 0.24 & 0.21 \\ \hline
07:15 & 0.20 & 0.22 & 0.21 & 0.19 \\ \hline
\end{array}

$D = \begin{bmatrix}0.23 & 0.21 & 0.20\\0.25 & 0.23 & 0.22\\0.22 & 0.24 & 0.21\\0.22 & 0.21 & 0.19\end{bmatrix}$

$D^T = \begin{bmatrix}0.23 & 0.25 & 0.22 & 0.22 \\0.21 & 0.23 & 0.24 & 0.21\\0.20 & 0.22 & 0.21 & 0.19\end{bmatrix}$

then how to calculate $D^T \otimes D$ ?

a paper said the $\otimes$ is nonlinear matrix operator (euclidean distance) :

$ \otimes(X,Y) = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-y_i)^2} $

Comment: The way $X\otimes Y$ is defined, it appears to be the Frobenius norm $\|X-Y\|_F$, and so it requires the two matrices to have the same number of rows and columns. But since $D$ is rectangular it does not have the same number of rows (nor columns) as its transpose. So I don't see how the operator can be applied to $D$.